# IDistributedCache available but the data is no longer in the cache?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, .net-core, distributed-caching

I am using the `services.AddDistributedMemoryCache()` in my .Net Core 3 web api `startup.cs` class. When I first set the cache:

```
public void SetCommandEventMappingCache(IServiceCollection serviceCollection)
{
    var cache = serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider().GetService<IDistributedCache>();

    var mappingList = new List<CommandEventMapping>()
    {
        new CommandEventMapping()
        {
            ActionType = "add",
            GrowFlowCommand = new AddEmployee(),
            GrowFlowEvent = "EmployeeAdded",
            TraceabilityCommand = "employee_add"
        }
    };

    cache.Set<List<CommandEventMapping>>(
        "command_event_mappings", mappingList,new DistributedCacheEntryOptions()
    {
        AbsoluteExpiration = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddDays(1)
    });

    //I am able to get back the command_event_mappings here.
    //Once the IDistributedCache is injected. the data is lost
    var commandMapping = cache.Get<List<CommandEventMapping>>("command_event_mappings");
}
```

In all the examples I have seen, this is typically how it is setup. The only difference is I added a couple extension for `Set<T>` and `Get<T>`. I did try it without the new extension methods and had the same result. The actual `IDistributedCache` when it is injected is available, but the data previously cached is gone. 
Here is an example of how I inject it.

```
public LegacyCommandBus(IServiceProvider provider, IDistributedCache cache,
    ITraceabilityTenantService tenantService, IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory)
    : base(provider)
{
    _provider = provider;
    _cache = cache;
    _tenantService = tenantService;
    _httpClientFactory = httpClientFactory; 
    //This is null
    _commandEventMappings = cache.Get<List<CommandEventMapping>>("command_event_mappings");
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var cache = serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider().GetService<IDistributedCache>();
```

Every time you call `BuildServiceProvider()`, you are generating a new container with it's own set of singletons (different from the ones injected using the built in DI).

The solution is to resolve your instance of `IDistributedCache` inside the `Configure` in your Startup class.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IDistributedCache cache) { 
    //...
}
```